# sed not working in read while loop

Tags: bash, sed

I am using read to make some file in a while loop. The code is:

```
while read var val
do
 sed -i 's/$var/$val/g' Hhh300_4L_gen.sh
 echo $var $val
done < "Hhh300_4L_config.txt"
```

Where in `Hhh300_4L_config.txt`, there is a line, for instance,

```
PROCESSNAME Hhh;
```

and in `Hhh300_4L_gen.sh`, there is one element: `PROCESSNAME`. So if it works, `PROCESSNAME` in `Hhh300_4L_gen.sh` should be replaced by `Hhh`. But it doesn't. However the output of echo prints correctly.

Comment: `'s/$var/$val/g'` -> `"s/$var/$val/g"`, otherwise your variable references won't be expanded.

Comment: If you're having the double quoted `sed` choke on a line, try adding `set -x` to the script before the loop so you can see what the commands look like after the variables are expanded.  Then you can find the value that is causing the problem--probably one that has `/` in it is my guess

Comment: Ah, thanks. The empty line cause the problem. After I delete all the empty lines, it works. So in this case, we can't put any empty lines in `.txt` file?

Comment: I added few commands to skip those empty lines. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If there is a character that doesn't show up in any of them, like, say, `#` then you could use that as the `sed` delimeter: `sed -i "s#$var#$val#g' ` you don't have to use `/` if there's something that works better for you

Comment: Hi Eric, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables are not expanded inside single quotes.  If you want `var` and `val` to expand you need double quotes (and make sure they don't have the sed separator, here `/` in them):

```
sed -i "s/$var/$val/g" Hhh300_4L_gen.sh
```

though if you're modifying a shell script (as I'm guessing might be from the `.sh`) there are probably better ways to do it, like having your `.txt` file store things as `var=val` instead of with white space separating them, then just source it from the script.

Comment: Also thanks for all your replies. In fact, that is what I first used. If using double quotes, I would get error:`sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression`. Then I changed to `sed -i "s/'$var'/'$val'/g" Hhh300_4L_gen.sh`, didn't work, either. And just to correct the example, it should be PROCESSNAME Hhh300_4L.

Comment: @maosenzhou that sounds like you probably have a `/` in one of your values

Comment: I attach a part of `.txt` file here:
`##process name`
`PROCESSNAME Hhh300_4L`
`##process config`
`MODEL Hheft_UFO2`
`DEFINE define w = w+ w- define l = l+ l- define vv = vl vl~`
`PROCESSCMD generate p p > h2, (h2 > h h, (h > w+ w-, w > l vv), (h > w+ w-, w > l vv))` (Since I'm new to this, I don't how to make a list here..each block is corresponding to a line the `.txt` file)
Does it look OK?
By the way, `.sh` file is not a real shell script, which will be passed to another package.

Comment: @maosenzhou comments don't format very well, and other people won't find the information very readily in them.  Instead, could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44828563/edit) your question with the new information.  In general it's helpful if you have sample input, desired output and actual error messages and the like to show how things aren't working as desired

Comment: I edit it, each block is corresponding to a line. Basically, I want each variable in `Hhh300_4L_gen.sh` is replaced by its value. But it doesn't. `Hhh300_4L_gen.sh` keeps the same. But read and while work nicely, so I guess the problem hides in the line of sed.